# Python замена части запроса в в браузерной строке

Tags: python, строки, циклы, браузер

Как заменить часть браузреной строки на свою из файла так что бы он менял только конец и производил цикл, то есть менял и обновлял страницу пока в файле не кончатся слова
Вот как я это представляю
В файле baze.txt
1
2
3

```
members = open('baze.txt') 
browser.get(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'members'/
browser.get(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'print= 
('members')/ 
 .click  #на объект
 members.close()
```

После этого браузер обновляет страницы по одной и кликает на один объект и так по циклу пока в файле не кончатся строки
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/1
.click
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/2
.click
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/3
.click

Answer (score 0):

В цикле проходите по строкам из файла и подставляете каждую в URL, например вот так:

```python
browser.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/{}'.format(line))
```